# Possibly unhandled Error with passing tests

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, sinon, bluebird

I have following method:

```
EventHandler.prototype.handle = function (event) {

    var me = this;
    return me.processEvent(event).then(function () {
        return me.saveLastSeenEventRevision(event);
    }).catch(function (err) {

        me.logger.debug("First attempt of event process failed, trying recovery");

        return me.recoveryStrategy.execute(event,me.processEvent.bind(me)).then(function()     {
            return me.saveLastSeenEventRevision(event);
        });
    });
};
```

And I have this test written:

```
describe('when processEvent fails', function() {

    beforeEach(function () {
        instance.processEvent.returns(Bluebird.reject(new Error('rejection')));
    });

    describe('when recovery fails', function() {
        beforeEach(function () {
            instance.recoveryStrategy.execute.returns(Bluebird.reject(new Error('recovery rejected')));
        });

        it('should not save the revision', function(done) {
            instance.handle(event).catch(function() {
                sinon.assert.notCalled(instance.saveLastSeenEventRevision);
                done();
            }).done();
        });
    });
});
```

I simulate rejection of *processEvent* method, and in catching function I simulate final rejection of my recovery implementation. I have more test written for this method, but the setup is the same. All test passes as they are supposed to, but in console I see this message:

```
Possibly unhandled Error: rejection
```

Is there any other way of handling these promises to pass this test?

Test setup - mocha / chai / sinon, as promise library is used bluebird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're creating an explicit rejection but are not handling it here:

```
instance.processEvent.returns(Bluebird.reject(new Error('rejection')));
```

Bluebird sees you're creating an unhandled rejection here so it's letting you know. This is because a real function would return the rejection when called but sinon is creating it early - so the app has a pending place of error that is not handled. You can turn that off with:

```
Bluebird.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection(function(){});
```

Or better, use a tool like [sinon-as-promised](https://github.com/bendrucker/sinon-as-promised) which lets you do:

```
instance.processEvent.rejects('rejection');
```

On a side note - don't use the silly `done` syntax, Mocha has built in promises support. You can `return` promises from test.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I solved the same way, with the sinon-as-promised library, you just answered faster :-) I already know about mocha promise support, with .done style it's just an old habit. (And the other one is that we haven't updated mocha's version at all projects yet, but we are workin' on it)

Comment: @Esailija how though? His code is explicitly creating a rejection and not handling it as a fixated return value to return from a method in a stud.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you can use `.reason()` or `.catch(_ => _)`

Comment: @Esailija where/how in this case?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `var rejection = Promise.reject(...); rejection.reason(); instance.processEvent.returns(rejection);`

Comment: Yes, that would require 3 lines instead of one though, just saying :D The correct solution is to not create the rejection ahead of time at all anyway - just like you don't `throw` ahead of time since it'd crash your program.

Answer (score 1):

So, problem was with sinon stubs and setting up return values. It seems, that passing rejected promise as return value is some how evaluated inside sinon itself.

There are two options:

1. to not set return value directly, but  implement function which will be used instead of the stub one

   ```
   sinon.stub(instance, 'processEvent', function() {
       return Bluebird.reject(new Error('rejected');
   });
   ```
2. to use **sinon-as-promised** library, which allows following:

   ```
   sinon.stub(instance, 'processEvent').rejects(new Error('rejected'));
   ```